# Setting up multiple parameter Values in a Sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, string, jsp, c-strings

Im trying to pass Multiple Parameter values from one jsp page to another jsp page.
How do i pass these values in a Sql query.

**First page:**

```
  <th>Revenue</th>
  <select name="Student" multiple >
  <option value="CST">CST</option>
  <option value="EST">EST</option>
  <option value="MST">MST</option>
  <option value="MDT">MDT</option>
  <option value="PST">PST</option>`
```

**Second Page:**

```
String[] t2=request.getParameterValues("Student");

if(t2!=null){
    for( i=0;i<t2.length;i++){
        out.println(t2[i]);
    }
}

String QueryString1 = "Select * from School where Student in ('t2[i]')";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Careful with SQL injection.

You can use your `in ()` with this :

```
String str_in = new String("")
for( i=0;i<t2.length;i++){
    str_in += "'" + t2[i]+"',";
}
str_in = str_in.replaceAll(",$", "");

String QueryString1 = "Select * from School where Student in ("+str_in+")"
```

Comment: Thanks It Worked :-)

Comment: @vijayGowda good ;) Don't forget to set your question as "solved"